# Decode a string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I decode a string in swift? The string is now `test%2Enl`, but the correct format is `test.nl`.

I now have this:

```
 let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)!
 let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
 let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!

 return attributedString.string
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

```
var properString = s.stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

**Update for swift 3:**
Use `removingPercentEncoding` instead.

Comment: Deprecated : use `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`

Comment: Swift 3: `removingPercentEncoding`

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 3:

```
let encodedString = "test%2Enl"
let decodedString = encodedString.removingPercentEncoding!
```

Swift 3 removed a lot of "excess" wording in many of the Apple APIs.

In this case stringByRemovingPercentEncoding was simplified to removingPercentEncoding.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`?

From the docs:

> Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all percent encoded sequences with the matching UTF-8 characters.

```
let encodedString = "test%2Enl"
let decodedString = encodedString.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
println(decodedString)
```

This would print test.nl

Comment: "http:/%14/good" does not work, it outputs "http:/\u{14}/good" :(

Answer (score 2):

You could use SwiftString (https://github.com/amayne/SwiftString) to do this.

```
"test%2Enl".decodeHTML() // "test.nl"
```

DISCLAIMER: I wrote this extension